# Content not scrolling over the header/banner

Tags: html, css

So, basically i need help with the same effect as on this page: https://jsfiddle.net/WsXP6/126/

However, I want the top not to be a picture, but a solid color. 
Can't seem to get it to work... The content part doesn't go over the top part for some reason. Bear in mind that I have just started using HTML & CSS recently.

My CSS & HTML:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1rem;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
  a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 3rem;
}

.header {
    background: #0F1014;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.content_top {
  margin-top: 260px;
  padding: 4rem 0 8rem 0; }
  .sub_title, .under_title {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .sub_title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }

  .logo_middle {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .under_title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  }

.content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jakob Hoeg</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <header>
        <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="images/logo_top.png" draggable="false"/>
        <nav>
          <a href="#">HJEM</a>
          <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
          <a href="#">KONTAKT</a>
        </nav>

        <div class="content_top">
          <h4 class="sub_title">HEY, MIT NAVN ER</h4>
          <img class="logo_middle" src="images/logo_big.png" draggable="false"/>
          <h4 class="under_title">MULTIMEDIEDESIGN STUDERENDE</h4>
        </div>
      </header>

    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Jefferson_Park_in_Chicago.JPG") no-repeat top center fixed;` to `background: red;` and you're done. Taken from the first jsfiddle example you give.

Comment: If you look at my CSS, I've already changed that to #0F1014 but it still doesn't work?

Comment: Could you update the jsFiddle by pressing the "Update" button, then paste the new url in here so we can see your code in action. If I do the background change it works fine.

Comment: Ya, so you've got a few problems in your example. For starters, your #wrapper div is closed inside your `<section>` so you're breaking your DOM right off the bat. Second is how your DOM is created overall in comparison to your jsfiddle example you're following.

Comment: I accidently uploaded a wrong HTML file. Please check the new one. Thanks for the answers too, though. My bad..

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code
https://jsfiddle.net/WsXP6/268/

css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#banner{
  background-color:#fff;

}
#logo{

}
nav{
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  }
nav a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#444;
  padding:0 5px;
}
h4{
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 0;
}
.content{
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:60px 0;
}
.sub_title{
  text-align:center;
}
.content img{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
.under_title{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Could you try to be more specific on what is wrong in my HTML or CSS, instead of changing everything? Because that makes it a bit frustrating to work with, no offense. Thanks for taking time to answer though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link to a javascript parallax plugin. You gotta use javascript in order to get that effect.

https://jaicab.com/Paraxify.js/

Comment: So to get this effect without the use of an background image, I have to use the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'm not sure if you get parallax on just a solid color. But maybe you can find a image of a color you like and set it that way. But the parallax is usually for images. Let me know how it turns out

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yea, i found out that it indeed doesn't work with just a solid color. Atleast not the way I've tried to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to change the background to red.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1rem;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
  a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 3rem;
}

.header {
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.content_top {
  margin-top: 260px;
  padding: 4rem 0 8rem 0; }
  .sub_title, .under_title {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .sub_title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }

  .logo_middle {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .under_title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  }

.content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crystaloakley/WsXP6/275/

Comment: I might have described my problem poorly. I'm not looking to change the background to red - I've already changed the background color. I wan't to create the same effect as the jsfiddle i provided in the top - see my HTML & CSS - it doesn't do the same effect.

Comment: i did look at it but I didn't see an effect there. Are you looking to do a parallax effect on the background?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's the word I was looking for.